# Magento Promotional catalog rule is not applying

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

After adding a catalog promotional rule, when I click on save and apply. The page continuous to loads with out  giving any error. What's the issue I am not getting. It was not appearing earlier. Also If i just click on save button then the rule saves, but then if I click on apply rules on listing page, then its again continuous to load. I think the issue is with applying the rules.

Comment: Can you check browser console for any visible js errors.

Comment: @Muk There is no error in console